# Replace Null value with new line - I think

Tags: bash

These are exactly the same but first one doesn't work, second one works. Anyone know how to get first one to work? I think it's null issue. I tried replacing null values in first one but still couldn't to get it to work. Perhaps I'm replacing null values incorrectly?

1)this doesnt work

```
#!/bin/bash

export CSM_DATA_DIR="/opt/halogen/dbservice/changes/Ayman/test2"
export CUSTOMER_LIST_FILES="${CSM_DATA_DIR}/*_customer_list.csv"
export ELMS_STORAGE_FILES="${CSM_DATA_DIR}/*_elms_storage.csv"


paste <(tr ' ' '\n' <<<"$CUSTOMER_LIST_FILES") <(tr ' ' '\n' <<<"$ELMS_STORAGE_FILES") | while read first_name last_name
do
echo $first_name : $last_name
done
```

output wrong, should be two lines and should be split correctly

```
/opt/halogen/dbservice/changes/Ayman/test2/sl1_customer_list.csv /opt/halogen/dbservice/changes/Ayman/test2/sl2_customer_list.csv : /opt/halogen/dbservice/changes/Ayman/test2/sl1_elms_storage.csv /opt/halogen/dbservice/changes/Ayman/test2/sl2_elms_storage.csv
```

2)this works as intneded

```
#!/bin/bash
export fname="/opt/halogen/dbservice/changes/Ayman/test2/sl1_customer_list.csv /opt/halogen/dbservice/changes/Ayman/test2/sl2_customer_list.csv"
export lname="/opt/halogen/dbservice/changes/Ayman/test2/sl1_elms_storage.csv /opt/halogen/dbservice/changes/Ayman/test2/sl2_elms_storage.csv"

paste <(tr ' ' '\n' <<<"$fname") <(tr ' ' '\n' <<<"$lname") | while read first_name last_name
do
echo $first_name : $last_name
done
```

output correct, two lines and variables read in parallel

```
/opt/halogen/dbservice/changes/Ayman/test2/sl1_customer_list.csv : /opt/halogen/dbservice/changes/Ayman/test2/sl1_elms_storage.csv
/opt/halogen/dbservice/changes/Ayman/test2/sl2_customer_list.csv : /opt/halogen/dbservice/changes/Ayman/test2/sl2_elms_storage.csv
```

I've been posting questions for abut a week now all getting answer, I don't know what to say but thank you and I would hope to return this back to community one day

Comment: Is the asterisk quoted in the first example intentionally?

Comment: @user000001, even if it weren't, as the result is stored to a string rather than a list, it's the wrong data structure to use to store multiple filenames.

Comment: BTW -- `export` is only needed if you want to make a variable available to subprocesses by putting it into the environment as opposed to keeping it in the local shell's memory; and see  http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html re: POSIX-defined naming conventions (all-caps names are used for variables with meaning to the shell and OS, whereas lowercase names are reserved for application use).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original code actually has a number of subtle bugs. There are no NULs in your string to replace, because a C string (as used by bash) *can't contain* a literal NUL: They're terminated by the first NUL present.

Consequently, storing a list of filenames in a single string in bash (or C) is unsafe, because a file name can contain spaces, newlines -- any character other than a NUL. Consequently, there's no certain way to know when one name ends and the next one begins.

To safely iterate over pairs of files (which appears to be what you're trying to do), expand each glob into an array, and iterate over both arrays concurrently.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#              ^^^^- not /bin/sh, which doesn't support arrays

csm_data_dir="/opt/halogen/dbservice/changes/Ayman/test2"
customer_list_files=( "${csm_data_dir}"/*_customer_list.csv )
elms_storage_files=( "${csm_data_dir}"/*_elms_storage.csv )

for idx in "${!customer_list_files[@]}"; do
  customer_list_file=${customer_list_files[$idx]}
  elms_storage_file=${elms_storage_files[$idx]}
  printf '%q : %q\n' "$customer_list_file" "$elms_storage_file"
done
```

Note that the `*`s -- the glob characters -- are not quoted. This causes them to be expanded when the array variables are defined.

Comment: thank you, this worked, but why doesn't my code work in second example? Ignoring the "subtle" bug

Comment: "Second" meaning which? In the first one (labeled "this doesn't work"), it's because globs aren't expanded in quoted strings, so the replacement doesn't happen until the line with the `echo`. If you made it `echo "${first_name} : ${last_name}"`, with the quotes, this would be a bit more obvious (because this would prevent the glob from being expanded during the `echo` invocation).

Comment: That is to say, `CUSTOMER_LIST_FILES="${CSM_DATA_DIR}/*_customer_list.csv"` doesn't actually replace the `*` with a list of files, and neither does `<<<"$CUSTOMER_LIST_FILES"`; it's only when you run `echo $CUSTOMER_LIST_FILES` (without the quotes) that expansion takes place with your original code.

Comment: hmm.. the expansion is returning one value when I use it in my code in example 1, but it make it work correctly, not sure why only one file when I can clearly see two. Your above code works correctly, thank you for that. I don't know how to insert code here -       

export CUSTOMER_LIST_FILES=( "${CSM_DATA_DIR}"/*_customer_list.csv )


export ELMS_STORAGE_FILES=( "${CSM_DATA_DIR}"/*_elms_storage.csv )